# Create a HashSet that uses a custom condition instead of equals

Tags: java, equals, hashset

Here is the structure of the class that I am working with:

```
public class Foo {
    private final Bar bar; //Bar is immutable
    private int state;

    public Foo(Bar bar, int state) {
        this.bar = bar;
        this.state = state;
    }

    public Bar getBar() {
        return bar;
    }

    public int getState() {
        return state;
    }

    public void setState(int state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(bar, state);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (!(obj instanceof Foo)) return false;
        Foo other = (Foo) obj;
        return Objects.equals(bar, other.getBar()) && state == other.getState();
    }
}
```

The problem I am encountering is the following:

```
Bar bar = ...;
Foo foo = new Foo(bar, 0);
Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add(foo);
foo.setState(1);
set.remove(foo); //foo is not removed!
```

The element `foo` is not removed from the set because its hashcode changed as a result of `foo.setState(1)` and thus the hash set is not able to find it. The functionality that I want is for the `HashSet<Foo>` to organize its hash buckets and check for equality using `foo.getBar()`. Something along the following lines:

```
Bar bar = ...;
Foo foo = new Foo(bar, 0);
Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<>(Foo::getBar);
set.add(foo);
foo.setState(1);
set.remove(foo); //foo is removed since oldFoo.getBar().hashCode() == newFoo.getBar().hashCode() && Objects.equals(oldFoo.getBar(), newFoo.getBar())
```

To accomplish this, I came up with the following class:

```
public class KeyExtractedHashSet<T, K> extends AbstractSet<T> implements Set<T> {
    private final Map<K, T> map;
    private final Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyExtractor;

    public KeyExtractedHashSet(Function<? super T, ? extends K> keyExtractor) {
        map = new HashMap<>();
        this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return map.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return map.values().iterator();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(T t) {
        return map.put(keyExtractor.apply(t), t) == null;
    }
}
```

Are there any potential problems with this approach?

Comment: Why do you include `state` in the `Objects.hash()` call just use the `bar` only as `state` can be changed ?

Comment: Seems like the easiest solution would be for your hashcode and equality implementation not to depend on state that you don't want it to depend on.

Answer (score 1):

Implementing its own Set implementation is a hard job, easily error prone or less efficient.
For example, `HashSet` overrides and optimizes multiple methods implemented in parent classes (`AbstractCollection` and `AbstractSet`).

For example what about `contains(Object o)` ?

You inherit from that defined in `AbstractCollection` that has a O(n) time complexity and that is normal as a abstract collection doesn't have an abstraction level that allows to iterate faster on its elements :

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    Iterator<E> it = iterator();
    if (o==null) {
        while (it.hasNext())
            if (it.next()==null)
                return true;
    } else {
        while (it.hasNext())
            if (o.equals(it.next()))
                return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

while you could do that with your map as the O(1) time complexity implementation of `HashSet`:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
   return map.containsKey(o)   
}
```

But since foo elements are stored in values of the map, you should rather do :

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
   return map.containsValue(o);   
}
```

But it will not work as expected since `Foo.equals()` considers the `state` field that you want to ignore.  And besides `map.containsValue(o)` is not O(1) either as it iterates potentially on all elements of the map.

Same issue for `remove(Object o)`.

As another example imagine that :

```
Set<Foo> foos = new KeyExtractedHashSet<Foo, Bar>();
// populate, remove...
```

And later a method creates a new `Set` from `foos` :

```
Set<Foo> someFoos = foos.stream().filter(...).toSet();
```

`someFoos` is no more a `KeyExtractedHashSet`. It can easily be forgotten.

Long story short : you should reconsider your design and favor immutable objects as keys of your `HashSet` as this is advised.